# SAML: Provider ID Issue

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

So I am working with a customer trying to setup single sign on using SAML.

We need to set up 3 separate instances in this case (usually the customer only buys one platform from us so never had this issue)

Basically they aren't able to set up more than 1 on their server because they get an error saying 'A service provider partner already exists with the given Provider ID' when they try to setup the 2nd instance.

It is not possible for us to change this on our end as all of our other customers will be affected and even still as far as I can tell it is static and even if we changed it to something else the first instance we have set up will break I guess?

Is there any way around this does anybody know?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So earlier, each customer has one instance of application and one corresponding SAML-SP running. Now your customer has three instances of application and try to use three corresponding SAML-SP, which has same ProviderID and that gives above said issue while configuring with IdP. Is this your issue and deployment model?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your product acts as a service provider(SP) and your customer has an identity provider(IdP). As you state in the post, the problem is

`A service provider partner already exists with the given Provider ID`

which means all the 3 SP have the same ID. Try changing the ID on each of these SP and the customers IdP should be able to add all 3 of them. The rest of the things depend on the configuration of IdP and SP.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But the ID is set in a Ruby file, if this is changed it is going to affect previous setups with other customers?

Presumably it has to match all the time, you can't just change it so they can set it up on their serve without getting this error and then revert it back, it's not going to work.

Comment: Are three SP's (has same ProviderID) for three different applications (under same security domain) try to configure with same IdP?

Comment: Yes, that is the case here. Well three separate instances of the same application, just with different URL's for each of the 3

Comment: I remember seeing only the first sentence in your first comment last time I was notified there was a new comment. You seem to have added the rest of it in an edit and I didn't get any notification for that. If you are adding new detail, consider adding it in a different comment. Anyway, since ID should be configurable, it is a good idea to separate that into a config file that can be different for each customer/instance. To not effect the previous customers, you can keep the current value as default in the new config file.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sundeep!